# Has anyone heard of cases where SSL Certificate insurance/warranty paid out?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Has anyone heard of any cases where SSL Certificate insurance - sometimes called "warranty" or "liability protection" has actually been paid out? Or is that just a marketing scam?

[Godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate?isc=bssl001&mkwid=lLALEy37_pcrid_77790463311509_pkw_godaddy%20ssl%20certs_pmt_be_pdv_c_&aud=brand) (under "All certificates include"):

> Up to USD 1 million liability protection

[ssls.com](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-instantssl) (last blue square):

> Q: What does warranty mean?
>
> A: If data transmitted via a secure connection is stolen, Comodo will
>   pay a lump warranty sum to the victim of such fraud. But really,
>   cracking a 128- or 256-bit cert is absolutely impossible.

Comment: I'm new to using this site - not sure how the yellow Q/A thing got up there (if AI, that's impressive) but it does not answer the question. I'm thinking it would even be hard to prove that it was an issue with the cert, or that it was cracked without attaining the PK. Therefore I think the bar is so unrealistic that the claim of insurance is itself really a scam. Likely never paid out - ever.

Comment: Question as it stands is off-topic as noted in discussion below. It would be more on-topic if you focused on the more technical aspects of whether data via a secure connection can be stolen (paraphrased from Q/A above), but even that is pretty broad.. see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-safe-is-ssl. Your question does not relate to information security, but more on legal questions such as how do you prove that it was stolen, and do you know anyone who has claimed such a warranty.

Comment: Related blog post: Scott Helme, 2018-02-28, [*Do SSL warranties protect you? As much as rocks keep tigers away...*](https://scotthelme.co.uk/do-ssl-warranties-protect-you-as-much-as-rocks-keep-tigers-away/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/djxvv).)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your question is that such a pay out would require that there be a fundamental flaw in the implementation of TLS and that the paid warranty would be under a strict NDA. If it has been paid out, no one *would* know. And, it is unlikely to ever need paying out (given the nature of TLS certificates).

But I'm concerned about your concerns either/or this being a "scam". It's an easy "bonus" for the vendor to add because the risk is low of ever needing to pay out. That does not mean that it is a scam. If someone could prove harm, and the vendor did not pay out, then there would be press about that fact. I could offer you protection, free of charge, against dragon attacks, and that does not make it a scam.

Comment: I think you owe some folks a payout then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon#Danger_to_humans

Comment: So you are claiming that selling protection from dragon attacks is something the FTC would not have a problem with?

Comment: @DP07 1) where is it being sold? 2) Why does the FTC come into it? 3) Why would they have a problem?

Comment: If you know it would never need to be paid out, or that nobody can ever know it was paid out, then I fail to see how this is not a form of extortion - because a $1 million protection IMPLIES there are REAL alternative scenarios where you can be forced to pay $1 million - though you know it's really not true.

Comment: @DP07 none of this is a security question but a question about the fundamentals of insurance. I have worked for an insurance company, but this is not the place to sort this out. There is nothing wrong with the bonus protection. You also have a flawed understanding about the nature and requirements of "extortion".

Comment: Extortion is the act of obtaining something through threat. Is this not marketing a threat (that you know is not real) - use these products and you might be forced to pay out 1 million dollars. Doesn't the FTC cover deceptive advertising?

Comment: Eccomerce requires SSL just as a coffee shop "requires protection Big Al is selling"

Comment: @DP07 I'm sorry but your logic is so flawed, I don't know where to start. There is no threat being made. There is no "payout of 1 million". There is no deceptive advertising. There is no cost for protection. You want there to be a bad guy and you are twisting the facts to suit your hypothesis. And no, questions about *warrantees* is not on topic.

Comment: A warranty discussion would not reveal that TLS SSL would never need to be paid by its design, so yes it is a technical question. Furthermore, if I told you that you should to buy safety insurance in case I beat you up but only I already know that I won't beat you up - how is that not a threat to you? They are the one making the cert! I can see your point if it was a separate company selling the warranty/insurance. BTW, certs can cost more for higher warranty amounts and are more expensive than ones without any warranty/insurance